# How can prevent parent dblclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can see the code below, I have two events:

1- `dblclick` on parent `target1`.

2- `dblclick` on children `target2`.

**Expect result:** when I  `dblclick` on children `target2`, I don't want run `dblclick` event on `target1`. How can I do this?

```js
$("#target1").dblclick(function() {
  console.log("I don't want this click when dbclick on target2.");
});
$("#target2").dblclick(function() {
  console.log("Click 2.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Screenshot" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td id="target1">
        target1
        <p id="target2">target2 </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `e` (event) parameter to the second click function and then use `e.stopPropagation();` within the second click event. This prevents click events from bubbling down and parent click functions from running when a child element is clicked.

```js
$("#target1").dblclick(function() {
  console.log("I don't want this click when dbclick on target2.");
});

$("#target2").dblclick(function(e) {
  console.log("Click 2.");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Screenshot" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td id="target1">
        target1
        <p id="target2">target2 </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In target2, you need to capture the event and prevent it from bubbling up. You can do this by calling `stopPropagation` on the `event`.

```
$( "#target2" ).dblclick(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log( "Click 2." );
});
```

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$("#target1").dblclick(function() {
  console.log("I don't want this click when dbclick on target2.");
});
$("#target2").dblclick(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Screenshot" style="height:200px; width:300px;">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td id="target1">
        target1
        <p id="target2">target2 </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```